# hashlib.md5 python2 vs python3 (string vs bytes)

Tags: python, string, byte, md5, hashlib

I generate hash with hashlib.md5 in both: python2 and python3.
python2 outputs string while python3 outputs bytes.
I have to use "latin1" encoding on string in python3 to match default python2 encoding.

I want to be sure python3 outputs same result as python2 and use string for further processing.

Question: How to ensure / convert md5 output string?

The reason is my python2 is valid output and I am migrating script from py2 to py3 so would like to validate the output but at the moment I can not compare bytes with string.

python2:

```
import hashlib


s = "fred"
hashlib.md5("fred").digest()
```

out: 'W\n\x90\xbf\xbf\x8c~\xab]\xc5\xd4\xe2h2\xd5\xb1'

python3:

```
import hashlib


s = "fred"
hashlib.md5("fred".encode("latin1")).digest()
```

out: b'W\n\x90\xbf\xbf\x8c~\xab]\xc5\xd4\xe2h2\xd5\xb1'

Comment: Hey! I did not quite understand your question ... do you want to always convert the output to a string? Then just use the builtin `str` function ... or what exactly are you asking? I think this requires an edit

Comment: in python3: str(hashlib.md5("fred".encode("latin1")).digest())[2:-1] is different than in python2: hashlib.md5("fred").digest() as extra \ are added

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by using `md5.hexdigest()`, this will return a string in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```py
from hashlib import md5

hash_ = md5()
hash_.update(b"test")
print(hash_.hexdigest())
```

Python 3 result:

```py
'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
```

Python 2 result:

```
'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
```

Comment: original python2 code uses digest() and does some character replacements on the returned string.

Comment: So you can not replace ```digest()``` with ```hexdigest()```?

Comment: if I use hexdigest then I return completely different string

Comment: I can not replace digest() with hexdigest() due to logic after

Comment: Why not eliminate the post processing logic? If you put the same string in for both versions of Python, ```hexdigest()``` will return the exact same hash for both versions of Python.

Comment: imagine you work on a car and you want to repair tyre while you are aware replacing car is better soluiton but actualy you can not to do it as it is not your car. so, you want to repair tyre. you are telling me to replace the car.

Comment: I know I can do it but it is not the point behind the question.